# Programmatically add menus to SPWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch does not work

Tags: visual-studio, navigation, custom, quick-launch

I'm trying to add some menus to the "Quick Launch" navigation and it does not work. I'm using the following code:

```
var ql = myWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
SPNavigationNode m1 = new SPNavigationNode("MainMenu", "");
ql.AddAsLast(m1);

SPNavigationNode m2 = new SPNavigationNode("OptionMenu", @"http://www.google.com", true);

ql[ql.Count - 1].Children.AddAsLast(m2);
ql[ql.Count - 1].Update();
```

I can't for the life of me understand what the issue is. No menu is shown.

If I look with power-shell at the `QuickLaunch` I see the "MainMenu" and the "OptionMenu" in the navigation but nothing is displayed. The `IsVisible` property is true.

Any hints?

Comment: I think Navigation codes are different between Publishing and Team site. I can't confirm it. Go a quick Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figure your problem is that you have not specified URL for MainMenu. As you notice all links in QuickLaunch has link associated with it. Specify a Url and it should work (I tested that locally).

Comment: perfect. is there any way to query straight (direct access) if i want to get items in those list that linked?